# XSLT - how to get a localized date pattern string from an xs:date?

Tags: xslt, date, xslt-1.0, date-format

I need to transform an XML that contains a number of xs:date values. 

Is there a better(cleaner) way to produce a string with a localized date pattern from these xs:date fields than just concatenating substrings?

UPD: I mean xsl v1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, use the format-date() function.

In XSLT 1.0, consider the exslt dates-and-times library.

Comment: I'm on v1.0 and exslt dates-and-times won't work as the processor doesn't support this library.

Comment: Without extensions, I suspect the OP is going to have to use string functions: concat(), substring() etc.